# diagonalizability and invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My question is about linear algebra, especially invariant subspaces and  diagonalizability. Here is the question:

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable linear operator on the finite dimensional vector space over a field, and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$  which is invariant under $A$.
Let us denote by $A_W$ the restriction of $A$ to $W$. I need to prove that $A_W$ is diagonalizable.

How can I prove that?

thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial of $A_w$ clearly divides the minimal polynomial of $A$, what does this tell you?